# Proving that g $\circ$ f is uniformly continuous on A.

Tags: calculus

I am trying to prove
Suppose that f is uniformly continuous on A, that g is uniformly continuous on B, and that f(x) is in B for all x in A. Prove that g $\circ$ f is uniformly continuous on A.

My proof is:

We want to show that for every $\in$ $>$ 0, $\exists$ $\delta$ $>$ such that for any x, y $\in$ A with $\mid x - y \mid$ $<$ $\delta$ $\mid g(f(n)) - g(f(y)) \mid < \epsilon$

Fix $\epsilon >$ 0.  Since g is uniformly continuous on B, there exists n $>$ 0

such that for any w, z $\leqq$ B with $\mid W - Z \mid <$ n, $\mid g(w) - g(z) \mid < \epsilon$.

$\because$ f is uniformly continuous on A, there exists $\delta >$ 0

such that this $\delta$ is the one we want.  To that end, fix x, y $\in$ A with $\mid x - y \mid < \delta$.  Let w = f(x) and z = f(y).

Then by our choice of $\delta$,

$\mid w - z \mid$ = $\mid f(n) - f(y) \mid <$ n.

By our choice of n,

$\mid g(f(n)) \mid$ = $\mid g(w) - g(z) \mid$ $<$ $\epsilon$.

$\Rightarrow$ g $\circ$ f is uniformly continuous on A.

Is this a correct and complete proof?  If not, any suggestions on improvement would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is quite wrong. I'm not sure if its because of your understanding or because of formmating issues. If it's the latter you should type up posts in MathJax on this site. There's quite a few missing characters such as an implies in your definition of uniform continuity. Also you cannot use uppercase and lower case variables interchangably as readers will assume they are different variables.

Here's how I would do the proof.

Uniform continuity: for all $\epsilon >0$ there exists a $\delta> 0$ such that $|x-y|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-f(y)|< \epsilon$.

Let $\epsilon >0$ be given. Then because $g$ is uniformly continuous, there exists some $\delta_1 >0$ such that $|x-y| < \delta_1$ implies $|g(x)-g(y)|<\epsilon$ for any $x,y \in B$.

We use $\delta_1$ in place of "$\epsilon$" in the uniform continuity definition of $f$. So there exists some $\delta_2 >0$ such that such that $|x-y| < \delta_2$ implies $|f(x)-f(y)|<\delta_1$ for any $x,y \in A$.

Now let $x,y \in A$, with $|x-y| < \delta_2$. Thus $|f(x)-f(y)|<\delta_1$. For any $x,y \in B$ and $|x-y| < \delta_1$, we get $|g(x)-g(y)|<\epsilon$ from the first paragraph. In particular $f(x),f(y) \in B$, so $|g(f(x))-g(f(y))| < \epsilon$.

Concluding, we have $|x-y| < \delta_2$ implies $|g(f(x))-g(f(y))| < \epsilon$ so $g\circ f$ is uniformly continuous.